# asp.net tag helpers not working

Tags: c#, tags, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, helper

Asp.net tag helpers not worked in my project.

I add this code to `project.json`

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
```

in `_ViewImports.cshtml` i add

```
@using Homebank
@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers"
```

When in view i use asp.net tag helpers - page not return data;

```
@model Homebank.Models.Admins

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}
 <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
```

Not errors, not exceptions. White page
[image]

Comment: white page is probably a 404 so it is not reaching your view, use web browser dev tools to see the response code

Comment: If i delete code `<input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />` its work perfect.

Comment: that is strange, sounds like adding that causes an error which is unexpected, have you tried it in the debugger to see what errors are happening?

Answer (score 3):

## Make sure your class has the property

Your tag helper is trying to access `Homebank.Models.Admins.Email`. Make sure that class has an `Email` property.

```
namespace Homebank.Models
{
    public class Admins
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I think that is the most likely fix, because your code works when you remove the `Email` tag helper. Here are some other ideas, though.

### Add a detailed error page

Instead of a white screen, we can receive a detailed error page. Add the following line of code to the `Configure` method.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // other code omitted for clarity
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

That will provide more debugging information. E.g.

[image: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource...]

### Restore your packages

It might be that you need to restore the `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers` package.  Here is how from the command line:

```
dnu restore
dnu build
dnx web
```

This is an unlikely fix, because your code runs when you comment out the `Email` tag helper, even though you're using tag helpers in the `_ViewImports.cshtml` page.